# how to add objects in arraylist in powershell class

Tags: powershell

i want to add items to arraylist object inside the class. how to do it. below is powershell code. it doesnt allow. how to achive this with
**1. array declared at global level**
**2. array declared at class level**

```
$logArrayGlobal = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

class LogManager {
    $logArrayClass = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

    LogManager()
    {
        $logArrayGlobal.Add("sada")
        $this.logArrayClass
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `$logArrayGlobal.Add("sada")` to `$global:logArrayGlobal.Add("sada")`

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot! @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell will allow you to write to non-local variables from within a class method body if you explicitly specify the variables scope:

```
$logArrayGlobal = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

class LogManager {
    $logArrayClass = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

    LogManager()
    {
        $global:logArrayGlobal.Add("sada")
    }
}
```